# GLFW window flickers despite blitting to it immediately after resizing it

Tags: java, windows, opengl, glfw

I blit to the window on the next line after resizing it. It only sets the window size once. It doesn't need to be draggable by the user. It flickers on the part that was added to the window, and on some occasions has the whole window flicker some kind of inverese image of the contents. It's tested on Windows 7 and uses Java. Is there something to do about the timing of the resize? It uses a locked frame rate that starts going when the program opens.

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
render(window, buffer.get(1), framebuffer);

            lasttime = time;
            Thread.sleep(max(0, 1000/60 - ((long) glfwGetTime() - lasttime)*1000));
            time = time + 1/60;
}

public static void render(long win, int rb, int fb) {
glfwSetWindowSize(
            win, 320, windowheight
        );
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_BUFFER, fb);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, 0);
        glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
        glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,319,windowheight-1,0,0,319,windowheight-1,GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,GL_NEAREST);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a thorough analysis you would need to post your code.

With the limited information given, I am guessing that if you are increasing the size of the window and the portion of the window that is added does a flicker it is because when the window is resized the same FrameBuffer and context is used but the Colour information would not exist from the smaller window into the extended portions and there would be a flicker whilst the new colour information is calculated and rendered from the FrameBuffer to the extended portions of the screen from your rendering calls.